# How can I extract and operate on specific values in a list in a Spark RDD using Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I am using Apache Spark with Python, and I have an RDD of tuples of the form:

Key, (Val1, Val2, Val3)

I need to end up with an RDD with rows of a form resembling:

Val3, Key, Val1, Val2

or:

Val3, (Key, Val1, Val2)

I've tried FlatMap, but it won't seem to work on my tuple lines. How can I access individual values from the list and operate on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spark, `rdd.map()` returns same number of rows as in the `rdd`. Since your output has same number of rows as input rdd, `map` is better fit. However, it is not wrong to use `flatMap`.

```
def transform(x):
        key, record = x
        yield [record[2], (key, record[0], record[1])]
rdd = sc.parallelize([('k11', ('v11', 'v12', 'v13')), ('k21', ('v21', 'v22', 'v23'))])    
rdd.flatMap(transform)
```

Comment: The variables inside the list only have positions, not names - val1, val2, and val3 are just dummy values. I need a way of accessing members of the list by positions like record[2].

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more clear about accessing elements using the index.